# When I used TextCell in listview, listview items are nulls

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

In my page I use a `Listview`, which is show files names in an directory.

When I used `TextCell` in `Listview`, `Listview` items are null.

My code for `Listview` items is:

```
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(myDirectory);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            if (Directory.Exists(myDirectory))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    lstFiles.Add(i + 1 + ". " + files[i].Name);
                }
            }
            lstviewsFile.ItemsSource = lstFiles;
```

My xaml:

- xaml that works

  ```
        <ListView x:Name="lstviewsFile" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding lstFiles}" 
                  SeparatorColor="#448AFF" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" 
                  ItemSelected="lstviewsFile_ItemSelected">
        </ListView>
  ```
- xaml that doesn't work

  ```
            <ListView x:Name="lstviewsFile" 
                  SeparatorColor="#448AFF" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" 
                  ItemSelected="lstviewsFile_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding lstFiles}" TextColor="#FFFFFF"></TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
  ```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lstFiles` is your `ItemsSource` - each row in the list is just a string (presumably, you didn't actually show that code)

so your binding should be

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding .}" ... />
```